# NativeScript Mediafilepicker Cannot read property 'filepicker' of undefined

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm trying to implement the Mediafilepicker plugin on play.nativescript.org using the angular version of nativescript, I have added the NPM package and implemented it as shown on https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-mediafilepicker. On the development environment I get no errors however when I try to run the program on my android phone (not attempted with IOS) I get the following error:

> Error calling module function TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'filepicker' of undefined File:
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/nativescript-mediafilepicker/mediafilepicker.js:7:36)

```
StackTrace:
(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/nativescript-mediafilepicker/mediafilepicker.js:7:37)
at require(:1:266)
at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/picker/picker.component.js:3:40)
at require(:1:266)
at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/app.routing.js:6:28)
at require(:1:266)
at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/app.module.js:10:23)
at require(:1:266)
at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/main.js:6:20)
at require(:1:266)
at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/__main.js:3:1)
at require(:1:266)
```

Code I am using below:

```
import { Mediafilepicker, ImagePickerOptions, VideoPickerOptions, AudioPickerOptions, FilePickerOptions } from '../nativescript-mediafilepicker';
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

@Component({
  selector: "gr-picker",
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: "./picker.component.html"
})


export class PickerComponent {
  loadMedCert() {

    let extensions = [];

       if (app.ios) {
        extensions = [kUTTypePDF, kUTTypeText]; 
       } else {
      extensions = ['txt', 'pdf'];
       }

      let options: FilePickerOptions = {
          android: {
              extensions: extensions,
              maxNumberFiles: 2
          },
          ios: {
              extensions: extensions,
              multipleSelection: true
          }
      };

      let mediafilepicker = new Mediafilepicker();
      mediafilepicker.openFilePicker(options);

      mediafilepicker.on("getFiles", function (res) {
          let results = res.object.get('results');
          console.dir(results);
      });

      mediafilepicker.on("error", function (res) {
          let msg = res.object.get('msg');
          console.log(msg);
      });

      mediafilepicker.on("cancel", function (res) {
          let msg = res.object.get('msg');
          console.log(msg);
      });



   }
}
```

picker.component.html

```
<FlexboxLayout>

  <StackLayout class="form">

    <Button  text="Upload Medical Certificate"
        class="-primary -rounded-sm" (tap)="loadMedCert()"></Button>

  </StackLayout>

</FlexboxLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, @mcairnsDDI. Could you add the template code for `./picker.component.html` to your question? 
I might be wrong about it, but it seems that the issue is related to a permission denied error. Did you tried to select another video file in other folder to test it? You could try shipping your component with a video sample inside your component's folder tree.

Comment: @FlavioCysne Hi I added the html file as you requested, I haven't been able to select any files yet as this error causes a crash on launch

Comment: Did you try any solution in the MediaFilePicker Git Issues related to yours? Like this: https://github.com/jibon57/nativescript-mediafilepicker/issues/80

Comment: Hi @mcairnsDDI
MediaFilePicker does not work in NativeScript playground. Because it does not support plugins that require an app rebuild.